# Why am I getting "psql: server closed the connection unexpectedly" from python script?

Tags: python, docker, subprocess, psql

I have a python script that first creates a postgres docker container using the docker-py library:

```
    client = docker.from_env()
    CONTAINER = 'test_cont'
    container = client.containers.run("postgres", ports={'5432/tcp': 27432},
                                          environment=["POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password",
                                                       "POSTGRES_DB=my_db"],
                                          name=CONTAINER,
                                          detach=True)
```

The docker container starts correctly. I'd like to run some commands from the python script, so I tried:

```
subprocess.call('psql -h localhost -p 27432 -U postgres -c "CREATE USER xxx WITH PASSWORD \'password\';"', shell=True, env={'PGPASSWORD': 'password'})
```

However, this command always returns the following error:

```
psql: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
```

If I run the psql command from the command line and not from the python code it works without problems.

Comment: I think the postgres server didn't start correctly. Please use `docker logs` to check your container status.

Comment: The container has started correctly, and I can connect to it from the command line and perform operations, the problem is only when I try to connect from python

Comment: You might consider a PostgreSQL client library, like [psycopg2](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/), instead of `subprocess.call(['psql'])`.  Is the code itself running in a container?  How are you verifying that the database has fully started up before you make requests to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem, if we run a postgres docker container in daemon mode it doesn't wait for the postgres server to finish the boot sequence, so the psql command was run before the postgres server finished booting. To solve it, I added a sleep time after the docker run command in the python script in order to allow the db to boot.